# How do government firewalls sit between me, the internet service provider and the wider internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, internet, firewall

I am perplexed on how are government firewalls set up between me, an Internet service provider and the Internet servers. How do they ban or some websites or slow down their speeds? When I am connected to the Internet via a VPN how am I bypassing the government firewalls?

For example here in my country Tanzania, East Africa from late months of last year to the latest dates of past month there was inaccessibility to Twitter but it was accessible via a VPN.

But my eagerness here is to understand the structure layout of how the traffic flows from me to the ISP to the government firewalls to the Internet servers.

Comment: There are only a handful of internet fiber bundles providing internet service to most countries, so when governments like North Korea, China, Russia, etc. enact their "great firewall", they set up a routing center at the access point for the fiber cable(s) coming into their countries, planting themselves between the internet and their citizens, allowing them to control the content that can be seen _(VPNs can bypass this, however not in all instances if the country blocks the VPN's subnet allocations.)_. Services like social media can be blocked by simply blocking their hostnames and subnets.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'll give a broad overview.  My apologies if this gets just a  bit political, but I think its neccessary to explain properly.

A VPN works by encrypting all traffic between the VPN endpoints - thus A correctly set up VPN of OK quality should bypass all restrictions if it can make a connection to an endpoint on the other side of the government firewall.   A correctly set up VPN should be detectable but not intercepted - which leaves the government the choice of allow the VPN without intercepting it or block all VPN's  (with many governments choosing to allow VPNs because it can be a game of wack-a-mole to identify them, and they risk upsetting big businesses who may show their displeasure by pulling out the country and reducing jobs).    It is possible to slow down VPN's if a government wants to do this, but generally slowdowns are a side-effect of the firewall rather then the goal.

There are a number of ways sites can be banned.  The most common are -

1. Intercepting DNS and blocking domain names where sites host undesirable content.  The advantage of this is it is relatively fast and light weight.  The disadvantage (to the government) is they can't see the traffic being viewed and its fairly crude in its accuracy as it works at a domain level.   Practically speaking it also requires the support of the ISP's in the country, and people with knowledge can circumvent this.
2. A government can cause ISP's - or can itself block IP addresses.   This is quite hard to subvert (from an end user point of view), but is also crude as it works at an IP level.  It can cause problems with sites behind reverse proxies, which is fairly common for large sites using Cloudflare and cloud providers.  (ie if multiple sites share the same IP of a reverse proxy, all risk being banned).
3. A government can intercept all requests and allow/block these based on the request.  This is fairly fine-grained and allows the government to look at context.  It is also CPU intensive and likely causes slowdowns.   The downside is that it doesn't "just work" on todays Internet because most traffic is end-to-end encrypted (eg https sites).   The way governments would get around this limitation is by requiring all users of the Internet to add a government issued root certificate - this allows the government to "MITM" (man-in-the-middle) the connection - effectively pretending to be the site to the end user, and the end user to the site, and seeing all the traffic between the 2.

It is possible for governments to mix and match the above technologies.   Its also likely that large players (ie Google) enter into agreements with governments [ in order to not be blocked ] and facilitate blocking for the government in return for being able to operate in the country.   (These deals are typically kept secret, but every-so-often leak out - I do recall some years ago Google taking a stand against the Chinese Government by refusing to co-operate).

As an aside, even in "so called free" countries, the dirty secret is that governments require large ISP's to be able to divert traffic through systems the government controls, even having special standardised protocols for handling this.   (In case you think I'm making this up, the New Zealand law - which is the jurisdiction im most familiar with - can be found at https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2013/0091/latest/DLM5178035.html and official commentary on equivalent legislation in AU can be found at https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/about-us/our-portfolios/national-security/lawful-access-telecommunications/telecommunications-interception-and-surveillance )

Comment: Can you explain in a bit a detail with diagrams if possible on the structure layout of my pc to the ISP to the government firewalls to the internet bear (without) of VPN connection.

Comment: Then explain on how basically the traffic flows from my PC to the ISP to the Go firewalls to the internet when I am masked on a VPN connection.

Comment: Doing this is not practical as there are way to many variables and ways intercepting can be done. Maybe the following statements are useful to you and might be worth googling if you want to deep dive - 1. An Internet connection can be intercepted **anywhere** between your computer and the server. 2. A connection is generally made up of hops between machines (the traceroute utility shows some if these, although intercepts can be done in ways invisible to traceroute).  There are normally a limited number of connections between ISP's - especially internationally...

Comment: ISPs can be forced to route these through the government firewall.  Conceptually to get onto the Internet you just need to connect to someone who is.  If you were running a firewall for your whole home  you would place the firewall on your router - as all traffic goes through that.  The government wpuldintercept traffic at the equivalent points in ISP networks, or in networks leaving the country.